# Manipulating and formatting the output of data frames

Tags: r

Simply, I want to print all the combinations of 1 through 5 as coordinates (x,y), and have the average printed beside it.

Now I'm a month or so into R, and this is what I've managed:

```
combination <- combn(seq(1:5), 2)
combination <- data.frame(combination)
combination <- rbind(combination, combn(seq(1:5), 2, mean))
mapply(paste, combination[1,], combination[2,], MoreArgs = list(sep = ","), USE.NAMES = FALSE)
```

So I have a data frame with everything I need, but what has me stumped is getting it printed like:

(1,2) 1.5
(1,3) 2
etc.

Can someone point me in the right direction on this?

Much appreciated,
Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
 paste( "(", combination[1,], ",", combination[2,], ") ", combination[3,], sep="")
```

This returns:

```
 "(1,2) 1.5" "(1,3) 2"   "(1,4) 2.5" "(1,5) 3"   "(2,3) 2.5" "(2,4) 3"  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

`sprintf` is also a nice option to consider since you can also easily specify the precision you want returned:

```
sprintf("(%.f, %.f) %.01f", ## Define the template you want to use 
        combination[1, ],   ## Define (in order) where you want to get the 
        combination[2, ],   ##   values to fill in the template
        combination[3, ])
#  [1] "(1, 2) 1.5" "(1, 3) 2.0" "(1, 4) 2.5" "(1, 5) 3.0" "(2, 3) 2.5"
#  [6] "(2, 4) 3.0" "(2, 5) 3.5" "(3, 4) 3.5" "(3, 5) 4.0" "(4, 5) 4.5"
```